# Replicate MYSQL JOIN query with Zend_Db join()

Tags: mysql, database, join, abstract, zend-framework

Hi this is my sql query

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, ACC.id, ACC.name
FROM accounts A
LEFT JOIN friends F ON A.id = F.account_id
LEFT JOIN accounts ACC ON F.friend_id = ACC.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

How do I replicate this using Zend_Db join?

I created this function

```
function getFriends()
    {
        $query = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
        $query->from(array('a'=>'accounts'),array('a.id','a.name','b.id','b.name'));
        $query->join(array('f'=>'friends'),'f.account_id = a.id',array());
        $query->join(array('b'=>'accounts'),'b.id = f.friend_id',array());
        $results = $this->fetchAll($query);
        return $results->toArray();
    }
```

But it only returns the right table, it doesn't return the left table...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `LEFT JOIN`, you should use `$query->joinLeft()`.

Sidenote; For performance reasons, you're better of using `Zend_Db_Select` instead of `Zend_Db_Table` select though:

```
$query = $this->_db->select();
$query->from(array('a'=>'accounts'),array('account_id' => 'a.id', 'account_name' => 'a.name', 'friend_account_id' => 'b.id','friend_account_name' => 'b.name'));
$query->joinLeft(array('f'=>'friends'),'f.account_id = a.id',array());
$query->joinLeft(array('b'=>'accounts'),'b.id = f.friend_id',array());

return $this->_db->fetchAll($query);
```

Note: make sure all your selected columns have a unique name. 'a.id' and 'b.id' will both result in column name 'id' in which b.id will overwrite the value of a.id.

Comment: Yes as you can see in my question, I know how to do joins, the premise of LEFT or RIGHT doesn't matter at this point because if you run the SQL in phpMyAdmin it should return a table with 4 columns. Zend DB only returns the first two columns. I can fix this by querying the same thing twice, but please... that's the dumbest thing anyone will ever do and is not good programming style

Comment: Make sure all your selected columns have a unique name. I've updated my answer.